# typescript type for an object where keys belong to an other type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an `appState` which I can update with an `action`:

```
type AppState = {
  contentWidth: number
  mapLayers: string[]
}


type Action = {
  [K in keyof AppState]: any
}
```

For example:

```
const appState: AppState = {
  contentWidth: 0,
  mapLayers: [],
}

// will set contentWidth to 200 in appState
const action: Action = {
  contentWidth: 200
}

// rest of the implementation
```

Everything is working fine until here.

But now I want to add an additional `type` property for each action.

```
const action: Action = {
  type: 'DISPATCH_CONTENT_WIDTH',
  contentWidth: 200,
}
```

I'm stuck because i can't figure out how to update `Action` type accordingly. I tried:

```
type Action = {
  type: string
  [K in keyof AppState]: any
}
```

and now typescript compiler is complaining:

[image]

How am I supposed to fix that error?

Comment: You probably want an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types), or you can do a mapped type also, but your code doesn't seem to be a [mcve].  As soon as I drop that into my IDE I see that your `Action` is missing a key: [here](https://tsplay.dev/ymAlBN).  Could you make sure the code in the question only demonstrates the issue you're asking about and does not have unrelated problems?

Comment: And do you really even want the type to be `any`? It should be the same type as the corresponding `AppState` value, right?

Comment: My guess is that you want `Action` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Gm32AN), but that isn't what you asked.  The short answer here to the question *as asked* is to use an intersection like [this](https://tsplay.dev/KwXPkw), if I understand correctly that the `AppState` keys are optional in `Action`.  Which, if any of these, would you like as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQUpgE4HswBBALigCIjyscCwAhM8+6gXww9EigGkIQAsgFcEwAJb4AdgGcAPDCgQAHkkkATaelYA+KKkzZsAbQDWUMZKgn++AGawoAMijTguCwHMAumQOH-XBBkAAYAIgCSMAAKRAAqAMIAEgD6ACRoJqzBNP7YAG7wADZCQbCmXjlQ7KymNvYKzq7ukt6c4NAA8sAAFhC4RADG4lKaqOQA6t2IEHl91BiBUIPDMnq8-MKiEjLyohC6AD5QXb39Q9vSGEA))

```
type State = {
  propA: "A"
  propB: "B"
}

type KeyMutations<S extends {}> = {
    [k in keyof S & string]: {
        type: `DISPATCH_${Uppercase<k>}`
        value: S[k]
    }
}[keyof S & string]

type OtherActions = "Whatever"

type Actions = KeyMutations<State> | OtherActions
```

Comment: Use the new `Uppercase<T>` utility type to make this even better: `DISPATCH_${Uppercase<k>}` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype